# How to put variable in array, wp_insert_post?

Tags: php

How to put the variable $get_value in the array, wp_insert_post?

```
if ($get_value) {
                    $get_value = "'post_content' => $postpost->post_content,
                       'post_excerpt' => $postpost->post_excerpt,
                        'post_name' => $postpost->post_name,
                        'post_title' => $postpost->post_title,";
                } else {
                    $get_value = '';
                }
$args = array(
                        'comment_status' => $postpost->comment_status,
                        'ping_status' => $postpost->ping_status,
                        $get_value,
                        'post_parent' => $postpost->post_parent,
                        'post_passworks' => $postpost->post_password,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'to_ping' => $postpost->to_ping,
                        'menu_order' => $postpost->menu_order,
                    );
                    $new_post_id = wp_insert_post($args);
```

Comment: This is really more of a basic PHP question, than anything to do with WordPress.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is $get value mean in your query ? Anyway, If you want to store another information related to post. You may need to use 'update_post_meta()' or 'add_post_meta()'

Comment: It is an easy question even on google Brazilian has nowhere

Comment: You should assemble $get_value as an array, not a string of key-value pairs, and you can combine it with $args using `array_merge($args, $get_value)`, or even just `$args + $get_value` I think.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the $get_value variable in the simple array and then you have to convert in the associative array after that merge both array into one then you can create or update the post through the wp_insert_post() function. you can achieve this by the following code.

```
if ($get_value) {
    // change the string structure for converting into the array.
    $get_value = "post_content,$postpost->post_content,post_excerpt,$postpost->post_excerpt,post_name,$postpost->post_name,post_title,$postpost->post_title";
} else {
    $get_value = '';
}
$args = array(
    'comment_status' => $postpost->comment_status,
    'ping_status' => $postpost->ping_status,
    'post_parent' => $postpost->post_parent,
    'post_passworks' => $postpost->post_password,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'to_ping' => $postpost->to_ping,
    'menu_order' => $postpost->menu_order,
);

// converting the string to array.
$string_to_array = explode(',', $get_value);

// converting the simple array to associative array.
function simple_array_to_associative_array($simple_array) {
    $new_array = [];
    $i = 0;
    $last_element = end($simple_array);
    foreach ($simple_array as $index => $value) {
        if($i % 2 == 0 && $last_element == $value) {
            $new_array[$value] = '';
        } elseif($i % 2 == 0) {
            $new_array[$value] = $simple_array[$index + 1];
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $new_array;
}

$converted_array = simple_array_to_associative_array($string_to_array);

// merge the both array.
$final_args = $args + $converted_array;

$new_post_id = wp_insert_post($final_args);
```